# Printing to PDF or on a printer removes all spaces

Tags: printing, pdf

When I print some PDFs (doesn't happen with all PDFs) all the spaces are removed. They look right in the PDF-Viewer, but when I print them (either on a printer or to PDF) all the spaces are removed. Here is an example:

Here is how it looks **before** printing:

[image: Before printing]

And here how it looks **after** printing:

[image: After printing]

Any ideas? I'm using an up to date Ubuntu 16.04.